# Is changing the pointer type of a private member variable in an interface class binary compatible?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom, binary-compatibility

```
class Type1;
class Type2;
class __declspec(dllexport) Foo
{
  public:
    Foo();

  private:
  Type1 * m_p1;
  Type2 * m_p2;
};
```

Can I replace `Type1` with `Type3` without breaking binary compatibility?

Background: Unfortunately, this class does not use the pimpl idiom. To remedy this, I want to replace the pointer `m_p1` with a pimpl-pointer.

Using Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Added the information.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some more background ? your Foo type is non-standard layout so just switching the compiler (even just upgrading) may break binary compatible AFAIK - this tells me you using the same compiler/machinery on both sides of the interface which seems to make the question moot.

Comment: According to [20 ABI (Application Binary Interface) breaking changes every C++ developer should know](https://www.acodersjourney.com/20-abi-breaking-changes/), changing a type of any class member variable breaks the ABI. Don't know how is this site reliable though. The same information is [here](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B).

Comment: @DanielLangr: The important detail here is that I do not change `Type1` to `Type3` but `Type1 *` to `Type3 *`. The size of the types are always the same, namely the size of the pointer type.

Comment: @darune: I use the same compiler on both sides, but one side is not under my control and so I cannot expect it to be recompiled.

Comment: @Fabian Ty, that was what I thought, but I wan'ted to be sure.

Comment: @BoBTFish As for your last sentence, I believe OP is aware that the library needs to be recompiled, but asks whether a program that uses this library (which is a _code that uses this `class`_) needs to be recompiled as well.

Comment: Right, so we need to know if the program actually uses objects of this class type in any way other that passing around pointers/references to it. Actually, I think my previous comment is more "smart-arse" than "helpful", so I'm removing it.

Comment: The pointers are private, there are no getters. `Type1` and `Type2` are opaque pointers.

Comment: @BoBTFish Do you think that creating an object of class `Foo` on the stack would be a problem? Assuming that both pointers to `Type1` and `Type3` have same size and alignment requirements? That's basically the point of the question I guess.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way `m_p2` can be accessed on the caller side from the code example that's provided.

Even then, this is very much breaking ABI technical speaking.

But if the assumption holds (100% sure that `m_p2` isn't somehow exposed) then ABI would only break if changing that type pointed to could change the layout of the class.

That would seem a little strange though - even when it's impossible to give a guarentee at the c++ language level.

Therefore it is a matter of checking wrether the layout changes between the two versions for the specific setup. That can be checked with something like:

```
Foo* p = 0;
&p.m_p1;//offset to m_p1 (make a static member function for the check itself)
```

Since there's no virtual functions on `Foo` we luckily do not need to worry about that for this class - otherwise that should be tested for as well to be absolutely sure.

The only thing thats left is any possible names that could be left - that would of course still be impossible to change - but in itself shouldn't break ABI.

Comment: I do not understand how the check works. Do you want to measure &p.m_p1 - &p? Is sizeof helpful for such a check?